# foreign key order in psql (database normalization)

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, database-normalization

student database that must be normalized 3NF and put into PSQL
I am having trouble with what order to insert into the tables in order to keep referential integrity with the FKs

attributes:

- student number
- name
- email
- year enrolled
- teacher
- course title
- course number
- department
- majors
- academic year
- term
- semester label (term/year)
- grades

These are the tables I created, I know I've messed up with the student table and probably the semesters one...or maybe I just don't know how to join properly. I need them to all connect in an order that allows for the f keys to be transferred to the proper tables but I can't make sense of it

```sql
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (       
STUDENT_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
STUDENT_NUMBER CHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
NAME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE SEMESTERS (
SEMESTER_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
SEMESTER_LABEL CHAR(10),
ACADEMIC_YEAR CHAR(6),
TERM CHAR(6)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS (
DEPARTMENT_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
DEPARTMENT CHAR(6),
);

CREATE TABLE COURSE_NAMES (
COURSE_NAME_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
COURSE_NAME TEXT,
DEPARTMENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES DEPARTMENTS(DEPARTMENT_ID),
SEMESTER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES SEMESTERS(SEMESTER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE COURSES (
COURSE_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
COURSE_NUMBER CHAR(6),
SEMESTER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES SEMESTERS(SEMESTER_ID),
COURSE_NAME_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES COURSE_NAMES(COURSE_NAME_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE TEACHERS (
TEACHER_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
TEACHER_NAME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
DEPARTMENT_ID INTEGER REFERENCES DEPARTMENTS(DEPARTMENT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CLASS (
CLASS_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
COURSE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES COURSES(COURSE_ID),
TEACHER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES TEACHERS(TEACHER_ID),
SEMESTER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES SEMESTERS(SEMESTER_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE CLASS_SCHEDULE (
CLASS_SCHEDULE_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
CLASS_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES CLASS(CLASS_ID),
STUDENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES STUDENT(STUDENT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION (
REGISTRATION_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
CLASS_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES CLASS(CLASS_ID),
STUDENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES STUDENT(STUDENT_ID),
YEAR ENROLLED CHAR(6)
);

CREATE TABLE ACADEMIC_RECORDS (
ACADEMIC_RECORD_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
STUDENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES STUDENT(STUDENT_ID),
REGISTRATION_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES REGISTRATION(REGISTRATION_ID),
GRADE DECIMAL(16,15)
);

CREATE TABLE MAJORS (
MAJOR_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
SEMESTER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES SEMESTERS(SEMESTER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE MAJOR_DECLARATION (
MAJOR_DEC_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
MAJOR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES MAJORS(MAJOR_ID),
STUDENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES STUDENT(STUDENT_ID),
SEMESTER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES SEMESTERS(SEMESTER_ID)
);
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Answer (score -1):

My recommendation would be to import all data without FK relations, and set up the relations manually after all data is inserted.
Temporarily getting rid of FK relations is a valid way of dealing with this kind of situation. It will often be faster this way to get the job done.